# How to redirect to error page when app crashed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router

I'm using React-Router in my project and I want to redirect to error page like 'Something went wrong' when app crashed.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: when you mean app is crashed are you talking about using it in development mode ? in production mode it will be mostly error in browser console

Comment: Uhh, yes but I want to redirect to error page in both situtations.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after reading react docs. React 16 introduced a new feature called Error Boundries which is like a try/catch blocks.
You can learn more in the docs.

**This is the link:** https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).